# Exporting to unity leads to wrong rotations

Tags: export, import, unity

Okey guys I know there are many questions many tutorials about that. Probably I have tried all of them. But if I model something like that.
[image]

I mean if a model contains more than one parent its going to be always rotation problem in unity someobject always shows -90 on X like that
[image]

I tried all settings on exporting panel tried some addons but couldnt figure it. Please help me on this what am I doing wrong because it really makes me sick just want model same rotations on Unity as blender.

Comment: You likely don't have the rotation applied to HatchCover_Bottom. Select it in the scene or outline and check if there is X rotation. To apply the rotation press CTRL+A and select rotation.

Comment: Thanks for reply but it is not my problem also in blender HatchCover_Bottom rotations are 0 0 0